# Session timeout in iFrame when use SSO with IdentityServer 4

Tags: c#, iframe, model-view-controller, identityserver4, session-timeout

**My scenario:**

App_1 & App_2 are my MVC web applications. App_1 is MVC 4.5, App_2 is MVC.NET Core 2.

I use IdentityServer4 for SSO.

I have a page to login and do the authentication stuffs with IdentityServer4

In App_1, i used iFrame to embedded App_2 inside.
App_1 & App_2 are same domain, different sub-domain

Now, i login to App_1 via login page by Internet Explorer. After login successful, UM redirect me to App_1 and i can work with App_1 & App_2 as normally. I can show the content of App_2 inside App_1, work with App_2 features...

I also set Session timeout for both 2 apps are 6 hours.

However, When i have worked a while in App_1 (1-2hours), App_2 will lose its session in iFrame and show the error: "**This content cannot be displayed in a frame**" as the below picture:

[image: Error]

If i logout and login again, i can access both applications normally, and then after awhile, App_2 will be dead again and the same error will be shown.

Any suggestion what's happened and how to resolve this issue?

Comment: I had similar issue, but in IE only. Was due to csp configuration. Worked in other browsers so I'd suggest firstly check if this is same issue across different types of browsers.

Comment: it's happened in Chrome as well

Answer (score 0):

Navigating to the `authorize` endpoint within a client-app iframe isn't really supported by the protocol out of the box.

You could create some middleware to rewrite the `Content-Security-Policy` and/or `X-Frame-Options` headers to allow your client origin(s).

If you don't want to modify the IDS4 implementation then I'd recommend just doing a `_top` navigation but that would involve the apps embedded in frames to bubble up an instruction to the top level page that sign in is required using `postMessage()` for example.

We have a similar problem in our setup and in that world we only ever do `prompt=none` `authorize` requests inside frames. If a `login_required` error is return then we send a message to the parent to ask for `prompt=login` request in the top window. This did require changing the default CSP for the `authorize` endpoint to always allow the (very much trusted) host app origin though.